# How Decompress UTF-8 JSON Response from Server with Deflate Compression Android

Tags: java, android, json, utf-8, gzip

My private class implemented `AsynkTask<Void,Void,Void>`.

In `AsynkTask` I'm sending JSON with user information by POST request (UTF-8 type) to the server:

```
{
    "action": "user:auth",
    "body": {
        "email": "login",
        "password": "password"
    },
    "_client_software": "…"
}
```

And the response JSON with data for authorizing the session:

```
{
    "errorCode": 0,
    "body": {
        "sessionid": "fEfZEKATEPhC3EdIrqgrsWEb9fs5WWDT"
    }
};
```

Where `errorCode = 0 - Ok`.

But the response from the server is with Deflate compression.

**How I can decompress a JSON string from deflate compression?**

Class Requestor:

```
public class Requestor {
    public static String AUTH_ACTION = "user:auth";
    public static final String URL = "https://example.com";

    /*    {
        "action": "user:auth",
        "body": {
                "email": "login",
                "password": "password"
        },
        "_client_software": "…"

    }
    */
    public JsonObject jsonAuthObject() {

        JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();
        obj.addProperty("action", "user:auth");
        obj.addProperty("_client_software", "android_ics");
        JsonObject body = new JsonObject();
        body.addProperty("email", "user@domain.com");
        body.addProperty("password", "pass12345678");
        obj.add("body", body);
        return obj;

    }

    //    public HttpResponse makeRequest(JsonObject jsonObject) throws Exception {
//        //instantiates httpclient to make request
//        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
//
//        //url with the post data
//        HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost(URL);
//
//        //convert parameters into JSON object
//        JsonObject holder = jsonObject;
//        Log.d("MyLog", "holder = " + holder.toString());
//        //passes the results to a string builder/entity
//        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(holder.toString(), HTTP.UTF_8);
//
//        //sets the post request as the resulting string
//        httpost.setEntity(se);
//        //sets a request header so the page receving the request
//        //will know what to do with it
//        httpost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
//        httpost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
//
//        return new DefaultHttpClient().execute(httpost);
//    }
//
//    public byte[] compress(String string) throws IOException {
//        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream(string.length());
//        GZIPOutputStream gos = new GZIPOutputStream(os);
//        gos.write(string.getBytes());
//        gos.close();
//        byte[] compressed = os.toByteArray();
//        os.close();
//        return compressed;
//    }
//
//    public  String decompress(byte[] compressed) throws IOException {
//        final int BUFFER_SIZE = 32;
//        ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(compressed);
//        GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(is, BUFFER_SIZE);
//        StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
//        byte[] data = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
//        int bytesRead;
//        while ((bytesRead = gis.read(data)) != -1) {
//            string.append(new String(data, 0, bytesRead));
//        }
//        gis.close();
//        is.close();
//        return string.toString();
//    }
    private String readAll(BufferedReader rd) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String inputLine;

        while ((inputLine = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(inputLine);
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

    public void readJsonFromUrl(String url) throws IOException {

        InputStream is = null;
        is.read(url.getBytes(), 0, url.length());


        try {
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new GZIPInputStream(is), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            String jsonText = readAll(rd);
            System.out.println(jsonText);
        } finally {
            is.close();
        }
    }

    public String makeRequest(JsonObject jsonObject) throws Exception {
        //instantiates httpclient to make request
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        //url with the post data
        HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost(URL);

        //convert parameters into JSON object
        JsonObject holder = jsonObject;
        Log.d("MyLog", "holder = " + holder.toString());
        //passes the results to a string builder/entity
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(holder.toString(), HTTP.UTF_8);

        //sets the post request as the resulting string
        httpost.setEntity(se);
        //sets a request header so the page receving the request
        //will know what to do with it
        httpost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
            String line = null;
            stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
            }
            Log.d("MyLog", "sb = " + stringBuilder.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

}
```

Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "A";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        AuthAsynkTask authAsyncTask = new AuthAsynkTask();
        authAsyncTask.execute();
    }






    private class AuthAsynkTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private static final String TAG = "MyLog";


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Requestor requestor = new Requestor();
            try {
                String jsonText = requestor.makeRequest(requestor.jsonAuthObject());
                Log.d("MyLog","jsonText = "+jsonText.toString());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

In the log, text is written as the following:

```
D/MyLOg﹕ sb = x��VJ-*�/r�OIU�2�QJ�O�T��V*N-.����LQ�Rr�(+�5��.vO1t˵4��q2�L��OJJ-S����`�
```

**How can I resolve this issue?**

Comment: java.util.zip.Inflater or InflaterInputStream may be of help.

Comment: The compressed data from the server needs to be decompressed *before* the data is interpreted as a String object. Your code indicates that makeRequest method returns a String object but Requestor class must have another different method that returns a byte array or an InputStream object, which you should use instead of makeRequest.

Comment: Thanks. For answer, will be try now

Comment: @Klerisson, I don't remember now. If you have this problem you can use Retrofit (http://square.github.io/retrofit/) for REST communications. He has automatically decompression of compressed data from server